# Form url for existing Nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i have question to Nginx specialist. There are such rules on Nginx.

If i request with header 'main',  it adds  /ismain  to url:

```
if ($http_main) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /ismain/$1;
}
```

Next it cut /ismain/ from url and goes to Host

```
location /ismain/ {
      rewrite ^/ismain/(.*)$  $1 break;
      proxy_pass http://Host:9999;
}
```

It works good and i can't change it because of company sequrity policy.

But now i need to do callback and headers are not allowed.

So i request in such a way(without header):
http://11.11.117.111:8077/ismain/someaddress

But Nginx cut off all slashes after port...  and responses 400 Bad URI.
In logs i can see such url after cut:

**http://11.11.117.111:8077someaddress**

I tried request with double slashes:
http://11.11.117.111:8077//ismain/someaddress
http://11.11.117.111:8077/ismain//someaddress

But it's not work. I have the same response. I'm in frustration why i works with header, but doesn't want with my formed path.  I suppose it's the same.

Maybe i need to screen slash with some symbol ?   Can you advice me ?

Answer (score 1):

All Nginx URIs contain a leading `/`.

Your first `rewrite` statement is adding a double `//`. You should use:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /ismain$1;
```

or:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /ismain/$1;
```

Your second `rewrite` statement relies on the first bug. You should use:

```
rewrite ^/ismain(/.*)$ $1 break;
```

or:

```
rewrite ^/ismain/(.*)$ /$1 break;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I regret to say, but i can't  change Nginx conf.   My question is how can i form request string to fit in current nginx conf.  without 400 Bad URI..

Comment: You helped @Richard Smith me very much.  I decided my problem. My exact question had no decicion.  I fixed problem in config and it works.  Godd luck to you Richard.